# CSS <LINK>: Target Element in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I am currently using nextjs for a project. I got some problems.

When I use  it makes an element positioned at the top of the screen. However, there is a floating Navbar from app/layout.tsx blocking its visibility. So I want move the target element down to the center when clicked on  instead if possible.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

I'm currently trying scrollIntoView but still experimenting on them. No result at the time I'm writing.

Example layout.tsx

```js
//layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className + " bg-[#FFFFFF]"}>
        <NavBar />
        <main>{children}</main>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Example Navbar styling

```
<nav className="fixed left-0 top-0 w-full">
```

Sample Target element

```
//I want this to display in the middle of screen instead of top
return (
<div id="target"/>
)
```

Sample Link in the footer

```
 <Link href="/page#target">
```

Comment: Include some code in your question so that others can reproduce your problem. This also seems to be more of a CSS issue than a NextJS issue.

Answer (score 0):

use position absolute or fixed and top of calc(50vh - 50%)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).